# To get date from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column called as DateA. How can I select 'Yesterday_Date',
'Last_Seven_Day_Date', 'Life_Time_Date'?

```
DateA

2013-02-28
2013-02-27
2013-02-26
---
---
2013-01-30
2013-01-29
2013-01-28
```

For yesterday date I think we can do:

```
select date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) as 'Yesterday';
```

O/P:

```
2013-03-04
```

--
For example, if I have two columns Date and ID on TableA. On the select statement, If I say 'Yesterday_Date', it needs to display 1 day of data. If I say 'Last_Seven_Day_Date',
it needs to display last 7 days of data. if I say 'Life_Time_Date' it needs to display all data from table.

What would that select statement look like?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the **data type** for `DateA`?  What do you mean by "**Life_Time_Date**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this you go with

```
   select date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) as Yesterday , 
          date_sub(curdate(),interval 7 day) as seven_days_ago ,
          min(DateA) as Life_Time_Date
```

min mean the first date stored in .

Answer (score 1):

Your where clauses would look like this:

Yesterday:

```
WHERE `Date` = date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

Last 7 Days:

```
WHERE `Date` >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day);
```

All (Life_Time_Date):
No `WHERE` clause

Comment: What about 'Life_Time_Date'?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you mean by 'Life_Time_Date', can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I did and it works:

```
select date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day), 'Yesterday' union
select date_sub(curdate(),interval 7 day), 'Last 7' union
select date_sub(curdate(),interval 14 day), 'Last 14' union
select date_sub(curdate(),interval 14 day), 'Last 30' union
select min(dateFact), 'LifeTime' from TBLA;
```

Then I seleect Column[0].

Thank you all.